# How to add in Admob ads on top inside a videoview using XML?

Tags: android, xml, admob, android-videoview

here is my xml script. i cant seems to figure out how to display admob ads ontop of my videoview. below are my xml codes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.gallery.video"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:gravity="bottom" >

   <com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="myid"
    android:gravity="top" />


   <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </VideoView>
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Currently it is showing like this

http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/563/img1nve.jpg

But i want it to be like this

http://img854.imageshack.us/img854/1614/img2bv.jpg

Please help .  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this version.  I took out some unnecessary attributes, aligned the AdMob ad to the top of the screen, and set the video to be below the ad via the `android:layout_above` attribute.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.gallery.video"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="myid"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/adView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add the property android:layout_weight="1" to VideoView tag. See following code:

```
<VideoView android:id="@+id/VideoView"
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
             android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
             android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
             android:layout_height="fill_parent"
             android:layout_weight="1">
    </VideoView>
```

I hope this maybe help you.